# QR Code embedding in HTML using PHP

Tags: php, qr-code

I have this code embedded in my HTML

```
<?php include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
$vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:3.0\r\n
N:xyz; abc \r\n
FN: xyz abc \r\n
ORG:Example Organisation\r\n

URL;TYPE=work:www.example.com\r\n
EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:xyz@manya.com\r\n

END:VCARD;";

QRcode::png($vcard);
?>
```

But when I run it i get an error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HMS_AmanVersion_1.1\getPatientData.php:165) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HMS_AmanVersion_1.1\phpqrcode\qrimage.php on line 35
>   ‰PNG  IHDR««#&þZPLTEÿÿÿUÂÓ~µIDATH‰í–M®¥ …Ë0`† aÌØ’w^Ý€n‰Û
>   aÞbõA_ç½tOº·1÷ç#Aëçœ‚èÿõ÷52oÔÆTŽ ßLàSŽ
>   ©ÝÈx>µ:=ˆ‡²&;ÄFÞ¾#Íz„#/d'­ÖJÓS¼GÇ‰¹–-=Ã¤6ïíOsàå;xîùöåûþQ†Ç}¥–EóÚˆ(ÿßñXÝžøŽûCxå<Ë±!Kš&íöØ^ýæCŽ‰Ô'¹3Šÿbk´Úà_©ÝˆúýNny€Q4íŽPNßÞ5Ïº9"ac¤ù•ì˜ðW-rL(—Ï„.Žîƒœ'u>ÀPRm¯š
>   ”Mî“Ú$ÇÆ—Ã£òM„µ:§J†Qíë5(ÂÍ#»ãŽ×p®xMŒM=ÁÜç§vyÿ”cx&ÉÒ+_6XÎ¥u)¾zùvˆ>IÌo¯a¸æšÜàX8QZH|“ã~FFÇË5±Hyz€û¹ÕëdÚ³¾=Äje‹S˜ñ–áÑw…#òä6}÷
>   CCShÃuÜû¢#ß;óáZp¯yà6ËñÿëÏëPö8To±×1IEND®B

But if I run this file as an independent PHP file it runs and provides desired result. Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to "**embed**" the png into your HMTL using PHP like that.

In HMTL use a normal image tag and set the `SRC` attribute to point to the PHP script which generates the image instead.

---

PHP: image.php

```
<?php
include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
$vcard =
    "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n".
    "VERSION:3.0\r\n".
    "N:xyz; abc\r\n".
    "FN: xyz abc\r\n".
    "ORG:Example Organisation\r\n".
    "URL;TYPE=work:www.example.com\r\n".
    "EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:xyz@manya.com\r\n".
    "END:VCARD;";

QRcode::png($vcard);
?>
```

HTML:  mypage.html

```
<img src="image.php" />
```